# Constraint Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I had a weird issue while accessing the REST API of my application.
While checking in log , the error message is visible two times in the span of 60 days.

> javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000152: Two methods
> defined in parallel types must not declare parameter constraints, if
> they are overridden by the same method, but methods
> AppConfig#setApiVersion(String) and
> AppConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fccb006#setApiVersion(String) both
> define parameter constraints.

Note: There are frequent calls for the same API which worked most of the time. No recent deployments during the issue occurrence.
I am using Spring Boot `version 2.6.9` and docker image of `adoptopenjdk/openjdk15:jre-15.0.1_9-alpine`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it's a bug with jdk, please update to 15.0.2 
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8253566